# ¿Como puedo personalizar mi prompt con lolcat?

Tags: bash

**Quiero cuando cada ves que yo llege a escribir  en la terminal; se escriba con las colores del lolcat**

```
if [ -x /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/termux/command-not-found ]; then
        command_not_found_handle() {
                /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/termux/command-not-found "$1"
        }
fi

PS1='\$ '
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXkTS.jpg)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una de las preguntas más bonitas (y difíciles para mi) que he leído.